# Logout instead of refresh info on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I need to autorefresh select values onchange country-province-city

It seems easy, but when the event happen, call in first time to logout
Some piece of code:

Javascript:

```
$('#id_province_es').change(function(){
if ($('#id_province_es').val() == 0){
console.info("don't do nothing");
}
else{
var data = $('#id_province_es').val();
console.info(data);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/city/"+data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    var options = '<option value="">{% trans "Selecciona una ciudad" %}</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        options += '<option value="'+data[i][0]+'">' +data[i][1] +'</option>'
    }
    $('#id_city_es').html(options)            
},
error: function () { console.error("error al cargar las ciudades")};  
  });}});
```

Django:

```
def refreshCities(request,province):
    client = WSDL_CLIENT  # Client(settings.WSDL_URL
    data = ""
    try:
        cities = client.service.getCities(province)
        citiesList = []
        for p in cities:
            citiesList.append((p.pkCity, _(p.name)))
    except BaseException as e:
        o4aException = One4allCoreException(e)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, o4aException)
    try:
        data = json.dumps(citiesList)
    except BaseException as e:
        pass
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

And my chrome log. I do twice the change. First do a logout, and second it's ok

```
[22/Nov/2012 13:21:24] "GET /city/2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[22/Nov/2012 13:23:25] "GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[22/Nov/2012 13:23:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[22/Nov/2012 13:23:26] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7399
[22/Nov/2012 13:24:04] "GET /city/2 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[22/Nov/2012 13:49:58] "GET /city/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16
```

Any idea?

Comment: Now is solved!
I wrote a middleware function that override the request url in a prerregister page.
So, it was my fault!

Comment: Post the solution here and mark your own answer as the answer ;p